# Why are solutions in Chapman-Enskog formalism expressed via Sonine polynomials?

Tags: statistical-mechanics, kinetic-theory

Before I posit my question, I would like to thank anyone willing to have a crack at it.

I'm currently writing an assignment concerning the [Chapman-Enskog](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chapman%E2%80%93Enskog_theory) method of expanding the probability density function and using this approach to solve the Boltzmann equation, which appears in kinetic theory of gases. I have studied much of the standard material, e.g. Chapman and Cowling: The Mathematical Theory of Non-uniform Gases. However, this book and many other sources lack a satisfying explanation regarding the use of Sonine polynomials in writing the solutions.

I would like to be able to explain why does the use of Sonine polynomials arise in the Chapman-Enskog formalism. I certainly was not able to figure out if this method has a basis in some underlying mathematical principle (like how it seems ''obvious'' to express solutions to the Schrödinger equation as a Fourier series). Can anyone offer an answer?

Comment: I don't have any of my books with me to check, but the Sonine polynomials are related to the Laguerre polynomials... And in the Wiener-Askey chaos expansion, the Laguerre polynomials are capable of exactly representing the Gamma distribution when expanded in a spectral expansion. Not sure if that helps any -- does the Gamma distribution make sense for the assumptions in the CE approach?

Answer (score 1):

After a year I suddenly realise that I can answer the question :)

To put it succinctly, Sonine polynomials $S_{l+\frac{1}{2}}^{n}(v^2)$ are eigenfunctions of the linearized collision operator $L(\phi)$, which appears in the linearized version of the Boltzmann equation:

\begin{equation}
\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial t} + v_{i}\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial r_i} = L(\phi)
\end{equation}

which we obviously obtain by insterting the Chapman Enskog series into the Boltzmann equation and truncating at the linear term ($f = f_{M}(1+\epsilon\phi)$, where $f_{M}$ is the Maxwell-Boltzmann distribution ($\epsilon$ is assumed to be of order unity - equal to one)).

This and much more is explained in greater detail in the book ''An introduction to the Theory of the Boltzmann equation'' by Stewart Harris ([https://www.amazon.com/Introduction-Theory-Boltzmann-Equation-Physics/dp/0486438317](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0486438317)), which I would recommend as a quality reference to anyone interested in the Boltzmann equation and kinetic theory in general.